# In need for imaging details

Tags: c, matlab, image-processing

I am implementing a small imaging library for an embedded system as a school project and I want to provide the same functionality matlab provides. I have already implemented some basic stuff like reading images, thresholding, some cool effects etc.

The problem I am facing is that I cant find resources on how to apply filters (kernel based) on rbga images. I mean that I found something that uses a temporary sum for every color channel and for each pixel processed. I tried to do the same but I failed. The result is not the same with matlab. It is really important for me to have exactly the same result with matlab cause this will mean that everything is designed to run in matlab will also run with my code.

I was wondering if there is a book about these things. Does matlab explain how the functions are implemented?

EDIT

for example I apply the prewittX kernel

```
>> a = imread('Hydrangeas.jpg');
>> w = [-1 0 1; -1 0 1; -1 0 1];
>> b = imfilter(a,w);
>> imshow(b)
```

what I do is something like this

```
for i < img.height, i++
 for j < img.width, j++
  rsum = pixel[i-1,j-1].R*(-1) + pixel[i-1,j+1].R*(1)
  rsum += pixel[i,j-1].R*(-1) + pixel[i,j+1].R*(1)
  rsum += pixel[i+1,j-1].R*(-1) + pixel[i+1,j+1].R*(1)

  gsum = pixel[i-1,j-1].G*(-1) + pixel[i-1,j+1].G*(1)
  gsum += pixel[i,j-1].G*(-1) + pixel[i,j+1].G*(1)
  gsum += pixel[i+1,j-1].G*(-1) + pixel[i+1,j+1].G*(1)

  bsum = pixel[i-1,j-1].B*(-1) + pixel[i-1,j+1].B*(1)
  bsum += pixel[i,j-1].B*(-1) + pixel[i,j+1].B*(1)
  bsum += pixel[i+1,j-1].B*(-1) + pixel[i+1,j+1].B*(1)

  if rsum>255, rsum=255
  if gsum>255, gsum=255
  if bsum>255, bsum=255

  if rsun<0, rsun=0
  if gsun<0, gsun=0
  if bsun<0, bsun=0

  img.setpixel(i,j) = (rsum|gsum|bsum)
 end
end
```

I also don't know what to do with A channel cause I am processing RGBA images.

### This is the output I get

[image: my output]

### matlab's output

[image: matlab output]

Comment: just a guess: do you re-scale the result to use the full 0->255 range (matlab usually does things like this)? - also, make sure that the factors are all casted to float before being multiplied.

Comment: I am doing exactly what I describe in my question. If there is a negative value I changed it to 0 and if there is a value bigger than 255 I change it to 255. No I don't want to cast to float. I am using 4 uint8 to represent 1 pixel and my system does not support floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 5):

Simple image filters are implemented using [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).  Each output point is simply the weighted sum of the corresponding input point and other points in its neighbourhood.  The kernel is simply an array that describes those weights.  In 1D, it would just be:

```
y[n] = SUM x[n-k] . h[k]
        k
```

where `h` is the kernel.  Normally, you would calculate this independently for each colour channel.

Once you have the convolution working, the hardest question is what to do at the edges of the image.  There are various strategies (e.g. zero-padding, value-extending, wrapping, mirroring), but there's no one correct answer; it depends what your goal is.

You haven't explained what you mean by "failed"; was the result complete nonsense, or was it close (to within some error margin)?  If it's the latter, then you might be falling victim to limitations of floating-point arithmetic; Matlab may be calculating things in a slightly different order to you, leading to different rounding effects.

Comment: I'll try to add images and pseudocode later today. The results are not close so I don't think it has to do with floating point arithmetic. At the edges I decided to use zero padding.

Comment: @marcushatchenson: Ok, it's difficult to make precise comments because you haven't shown real C code.  But things to check for: * Are your pixel values 0->255, or -128->127? * How are you handling boundaries? * Are you writing to a separate output array, or back to the input array?

Comment: Values are 0-255 and I am writing to a separate output array. Sorry for not posting real C code but it is really messed up now.

Comment: Finally I found what was wrong. I was placing the A channel in the last 8 bits. I had to use the 8 first bits.